# AWS MediaPackage as an origin for a CDN (CloudFront)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, aws-mediapackage

The documentation for

> [OBS STUDIO TO AWS ELEMENTAL MEDIALIVE TO AWS ELEMENTAL MEDIAPACKAGE](https://d1.awsstatic.com/awselemental/workflowexamples/Workflow2_Example_OBS_Studio_to_MediaLive_and_MediaPackage.pdf)

Says:

> Note: To use this workflow in production, it is highly recommended you
> use the AWS Elemental MediaPackage endpoint as an origin for a CDN
> such as Amazon CloudFront. The AWS Elemental MediaPackage console
> includes an option to create a CloudFront distribution during channel
> creation.

Why is it recommended to use the endpoint as an origin for a CDN such as CloudFront, while the example works without creating one. What are the disadvantages of not using CloudFront as a CDN but leave it with the MediaPackage Endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can indeed deliver your streams directly from a MediaPackage
  end-point. However we recommend to use the MediaPackage end-point as
  an origin for a CDN like CloudFront because a CDN would cache the
  segments and manifests and deliver them to the end-users from the
  edge caches.
- This prevents the end-users (video players,    devices) from hitting
  the origin i.e. MediaPackage over and over    again for the same
  segment.
- For instance if you have 10,000 users spread across the globe playing
  the same stream without a CDN shielding the MediaPackage, all your
  users will try to retrieve the content from the origin
- Some of them might experience a higher latency depending upon their
  geographical location
- Having a CDN like CloudFront ensures that the users get the video
  segments from an edge cache closer to their location thereby
  improving latency and quality of experience for the users

For more benefits and advantages of using Amazon CloudFront please see the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc)