# Is it necessary to create a AWS CloudFront distribution for AWS MediaPackage when the clients are from one place?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I want to stream a live video to 200 listeners (web clients). I use AWS MediaLive and AWS Media Package. **All clients are from the same city**. From Prague. Is it necessary for me to create a AWS CloudFront distribution for this setup?

Thank you for help.
Tom

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its required, but [looking at the pricing page for MediaPackage](https://aws.amazon.com/mediapackage/pricing/) i suspect cloudfront would be faster (hosting) & cheaper, especially if everyones in 1 city, and that city happens to have a [cloudfront edge location like Prague](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/announcing-new-edge-location-in-prague-our-first-in-czech-republic/).

Even though this is on demand video, i bet its still writing to S3 under the hood - so the same arguments for CF static websites vs s3 static websites apply. Reducing the distance between end user and aws network edge reduces costs and is generally faster. You need to weigh this up against the extra effort to setup. Personally i would use CF

Comment: I found this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67431227/292216